# iBeacon Trilateration and showing user's position on a map iOS

Tags: ios, position, ibeacon, trilateration

I want to build a simple iOS Application with iBeacons.

I have four iBeacons and my goal is to calculate my room position by doing Trilateration. I want to show the room on the display, set the fixed positions of the iBeacons and then calculate the Position and show it on the display.

My problem is, I don't know how to start.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: i added an image from the room to the view controller so far.
Now how i can set the positions of the beacons?

Comment: Ok, you may want to edit your question to include those details. Preferable some code from your controller.

Comment: that was my question. Can someone give me a little hint how to start? there isn't much code in my controller yet

Comment: I get that it's kind of a catch 22 that you need code to get started, and to get started someone needs to provide a bootstrap. Even if there isn't much code in the controller, that little snippet would really improve the question and make it answerable.

Comment: You should give us some more info on which part you are stuck on.   You don't know how to triangulate to find the position?  You don't know how to communicate with an iBeacon?  You don't know how to get a basic view controller up and running?    Etc.   Otherwise this will get closed as 'too broad'.

Answer (score 5):

Even though iBeacons are relatively simple to use, trilateration done with them is far from that. The standard is meant for simply determining your current location zone from the nearest beacon. The zones are: immediate (0-0,5m), near (0,5-2m), far (2-20m). Due to the instability of the signal, it is difficult to obtain more precise location data.

That being said, there are a couple of companies that I know, who have worked with that issue: Estimote ([Estimote Indoor SDK](http://estimote.com/indoor/)) and [Steerpath](http://www.steerpath.com/). Maybe looking at those two solutions could help you get started with your project.